# A question regarding the sum of the inverse of all prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

If we say that every number is a product of prime numbers, then we can say that:
$$x=\sum_{p\leq x} \lfloor {x\over p} \rfloor-\sum_{p_1<p_2\leq x} \lfloor {x \over p_1p_2} \rfloor + \cdots + 1$$
Now, if we let $x\rightarrow\infty$, we have that:
$$x=x(\sum_{p\leq x} {1 \over p} -\sum_{p_1<p_2\leq n} {1 \over p_1p_2}+\cdots)$$
So, is this enough evidence to state the following?
$$\sum_{p} {1 \over p} - \sum_{p_1<p_2} {1 \over p_1p_2}+\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3} {1 \over p_1p_2p_3} -\cdots=1$$

EDIT: Consider now, that the question will be equivalent to saying, (that is, if the absolute value of every term summed is the harmonic series):
$$\sum_{n=2\;\omega(n)\not\equiv0\pmod 2}^\infty{1\over n}-\sum_{n=2\;\omega(n)\equiv0\pmod 2}^\infty{1\over n}=1$$
Where $\omega(x)$ is the amount of prime factors of $x$. Which is then equivalent to a weird thing:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{-\mu(n)\over n}=1$$
Where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) function. And as numerical evidence, if you calculate this summation up to $n=10000$, the result will be:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{10000} {-\mu(n)\over n}=1.002082699767482251957261311157953789974198663389559562494$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Can you prove so?

Comment: you've summed all inverses of all distinct $n$-almost primes for all $n$ at the very least ...

Comment: Well, $\sum 1/p = \infty$. So, does the third step even make sense?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy That is my question.

Comment: I think the problem must be the very beginning . How did you obtain the equation for $x$ using Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy It should be obvious. If you say that every number can be expressed as the product of prime numbers, then, to reach all numbers up to $x$, (except for 1), all you have to do is get the multiples up to that number of every prime number that is smaller than that number, and then, you remove all the cross multiples, which is the reason for the infinite summations. For $x$ finite, you don't need infinitely many summations, since at some point, they become 0.

Comment: It's precisely,

$$\pi(x)-\pi(\sqrt{x})+ 1 = x-[x/2]-[x/3]...+[x/(2\cdot3]+[x/(3\cdot 5)]...- [x/(2\cdot3\cdot 5)])... = -1 + \sum_{d|D}\mu(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]  $$

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Ok, the second point is true. But the first one is wrong, on my commentary I stated that the Sieve reaches the amount of numbers up to $x$, except for 1, and that is true for $x=6$. Because if we plug it into the formula I have in the question, the result will be 5, ($\lfloor {6\over 2} \rfloor+\lfloor{6\over 3}\rfloor + \lfloor {6\over 5} \rfloor - \lfloor {6\over 6} \rfloor =3 + 2 + 1 - 1$). Did I express myself badly?

Comment: Yeah I got confused by that. In other words, sieving is done up to $\sqrt x$. But, in your first equation, the indices should be like $p_1 < \sqrt x$ , $p_1 p_2 < \sqrt x $..not up to $x$

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Yeah, sorry about that... But still, if the indices were $\sqrt{x}$, then the result'd be $x-\pi(x)-1+\pi(\sqrt{x})$, because of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, so, the question depends on the indices being $x$. Sorry for confusing you man.

Comment: Right. The problem is the step 2. You've basically neglected the fractional part within each summation. For ex: $\sum [\frac{x}{p}]$ = $x \sum 1/p$ - $\sum$ {$\frac{x}{p}$}, where {$\frac{x}{p}$} is the corresponding fractional part .

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Consider the fact that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, and we let some other fixed value, say, $y$, then, one can say that: $lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor {x\over y} \rfloor={x\over y}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are wrong with the step "if we let $x\to\infty$": the asserted equation still has occurrences of $x$ in it, which is not possible if one has taken a limit as $x\to\infty$. If you mean the asserted equation to have limits on both sides, then every one of the sums diverges. In other words, the asserted equation is incorrect for most finite values of $x$ and is not even defined for "infinite $x$".

In short: when we take limits, we have to do so rigorously; we can't use $x\to\infty$ simply as a justification for a mental idea.

Edited to add: it turns out to be true that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}n = 0,
$$
which is equivalent to the "weird thing" in the OP, and is phrased in a way that successfully avoids problems with divergent series. However, this is a pretty deep fact—the typical proof uses the same machinery used to prove the Prime Number Theorem. In particular, it doesn't follow from the sieve-of-Eratosthenes argument given in the OP.

Comment: I very rarely downvote. I gave this A a +1 and downvoted the Q.